# I am having trouble to set color to my Greenfoot MyWorld class

Tags: java, compiler-errors, awt, cannot-find-symbol, greenfoot

I am new to programming and we have an assignment about making a Greenfoot game. now I am trying to set some colors to `MyWorld` but having some problems. 
 My code in `MyWorld` file is

```
   public MyWorld()
{    
    // Create a new world with 600x400 cells with a cell size of 1x1 pixels.
    super(600, 400, 1); 
    GreenfootImage bg = new GreenfootImage(600, 400);
    bg.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 250, 9));
    setImage(bg);

}
```

and it is returning an error

> cannot find symbol - method setImage(greenfoot.GreenfootImage)

The same code on one of the `Actor` classes working normally.

```
    public BgCells(){
    GreenfootImage bgBig = new GreenfootImage(200, 200);
    bgBig.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 250));
    setImage(bgBig);
}
```

Comment: Show class definition of your `MyWorld` class.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Is the method `setImage()` declared for the `MyWorld ` class?

Answer (score 0):

The method in Actor is called setImage, but [the similar method in World is called setBackground](https://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/World.html).  A bit confusing, I know.

Note also that setColor doesn't do anything by itself, it just sets the drawing colour.  If you want to fill the image with that colour, call `bgBig.fill` after calling setColor.